# Dynamically set sequence of work requests

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I have some long task, I want to smash it into several small subtasks:

1. first worker downloads list of tasks and enques n tasks acording to download result;
2. next worker do its small task: it does check, and if it is true, no more actions needed subtask finished, esle it enqueues next work request;
3. if check is failed: 3rd worker load data from remote server, if succes we enque new WorkRequest to store data on the disk, esle task failed (or retry);
4. if data loaded, last worker store data on the disk, if success, we completed subtask, else failed.

Totally we have 4 workers doing different stuff. Results from 2nd and 4th workrequest must be merged, into single final result.

My question is how to connect them, merge results, and how to enqueue work from each other?

Comment: did you ever figure out how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Android workmanager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced) library. The api provide something similar to what you need. It is called chained tasks.
An example:

```
WorkManager.getInstance()
.beginWith(workA)
    // Note: WorkManager.beginWith() returns a
    // WorkContinuation object; the following calls are
    // to WorkContinuation methods
.then(workB)    // FYI, then() returns a new WorkContinuation instance
.then(workC)
.enqueue();
```

Comment: My question was about WorkManager from the start

Answer (score 0):

To connect Workers, in WorkManager, you can use [WorkContinuation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkContinuation).
In this way you can enqueue multiple tasks as a sequence of steps building complex pipelines. This is explained in [WorkManager's documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced#kotlin).

Is it then possible to use [`androidx.work.Data`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/Data) as a lightweight container to pass data to the workers, but this should not be considered your data store. As an example you can take a look at how this was implemented in the [WorkManager's codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-workmanager/#4).

If you need to pass more data between the Workers, your best option is probably to offload them to the data layer.